# How do I get map item with Option[Long]?

Tags: scala

Below I have some scala that gets a key from an object map `m`, this works when I have a value just fine, but what happens when I have an `Option[Long]`? How can I get the map item?

```
object Main extends App {
  val mainKey: Long = 12345
  val m: Map[Long, String] = Map(mainKey -> "bar")
  println(m.get(mainKey)) // "bar"

  val key: Option[Long] = None

  println(m.get(key)) // syntax error needs Long
  println(m.getOrElse(key, None)) // syntax error needs Long

}
```

Comment: `key.flatMap(m.get)` - Anyways, this is your third question in a row, maybe it would be better to take a course / tutorial about the language? or take a look to the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) - Or, I would recommend joining the [**Discord** server](https://discord.gg/TEnUjefb) where it is easier to ask multiple questions and have a follow up conversation.

Comment: This worked!  Thank you very much. I have some very specific questions mostly regarding cases using option and I don't see that used much in beginner tutorials and when I search stack overflow I'm not getting much. I'd rather ask here and be able to come back to the questions as a reference later, and possibly help out others in the process. Feel free to add this one as an answer and I'll accept it, and 
/ or ignore my questions moving forward.

Comment: You aren't getting much because if you install an IDE like IntelliJ all these questions are answered with putting a dot after value and pressing Ctrl+Spacebar. Or searching available symbols with double Shift. Hardly anyone purposefully memorizes some particular API by heart. But you need to learn the basics (here: .map, .flatMap, for-comprehension, `Map.get`) first from a normal language tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val mainKey: Long = 12345
val m: Map[Long, String] = Map(mainKey -> "bar")
println(m.get(mainKey)) // "bar"

val key: Option[Long] = None

println(key.flatMap(m.get))
```

prints:

```
Some(bar)
None
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/6CdEul3sTvGa9gMyamKFEQ